# add SQL values to a ArrayList and then check if they are there

Tags: java, android

How can I add SQL values to a ArrayList and then check if there is x value on that list . Imagine I added values 5,7,8,9,10 , and then I check if there is 6 and It would return false. How do I do it ?

Comment: first of all you have to check if the list contains the object you want to search and then check what is the value of the object that you found that the list contains!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the .contains(6) method on your Arraylist. e.g.:

```
public static boolean doesNumberExist(int numberToFind) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT number from DB";

        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("");){

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                int num = rs.getInt ("number");
                // ADD NUMBER TO THE LIST
                nums.add(num);
            }   
        }
        finally{
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
        }
        // RETURN IF LIST CONTAINS NUMBER OR NOT
        return nums.contains(numberToFind);
    }
```

Comment: So I have an arrayList named DatesList , I already have items on it can you edit the code in that context?

Comment: Just use return dateList.contains(...);

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Mysql you can do with jdbcTemplate with the method queryForLists as you can see below:

```
public List getAllProducts() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        String query = "SELECT * FROM Products";
        List<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);

        for(Map row : rows){

            //Here you can validate whatever you want before save it into list

            Products product = new Products();  
            product.setId((int)(row.get("id")));
            product.setProductName((String)(row.get("productName")));
            product.setProductDescription((String)(row.get("productDescription")));
            product.setProductPrice((BigDecimal)(row.get("productPrice")));

            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[]) row.get("productImage");
            byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(imageAsBytes);
            String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");

            product.setProductStock((int)(row.get("productStock")));
            product.setProductImage(base64Encoded);
            products.add(product);
        }

        return products;
    };
```

regards,

Comment: So I have an arrayList named DatesList , I already have items on it can you edit the code in that context?

Comment: can you show me your code? Only the method that you want to modify

Comment: I have already done it it was very easy actually, just did ArrayList.contains(value) , I would have ticked you right but I can only do that to one person and he did talk about.contains , but I upvoted you. Well if I could tick right both of you I would :(